# Android question mark in TextView?

Tags: android, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters, file-encodings

I have a problem with accented characters in a TextView in an Android activity. The rendering shows me question marks instead chars "è" and "à". The flow is: Get a midi file from web resource --> extract lyrics --> put lyrics in a TextView. I don't understand if is a problem with encoding or charset. I try to encode a file with "UTF-8" or "ISO..." but every attempt failed. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If they are showing up as `?`, that usually implies that a glyph is missing in the font. However, those characters should be supported.

Comment: I confirm these charaters exist in the Android **standard font**, as they are present in Italian language. I suppose that the original file isn't **UTF-8 encoded** OR you are using a custom font.

Comment: You have to know the encoding of the lyrics; it's unlikely to be UTF-8.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm trying to change a font

Comment: @CL The problem is that the file is a midi and I don't understand how to extract encoding informations for lyrics sequence.

Comment: MIDI files do not have encoding information.

Comment: OK. Therefore it's impossible know lyrics encoding. That's true?

Comment: @CommonsWare, Der Golem, I have tried to change font but the activity show question marks again. I think that the problem occur when I get a file from web. I have tried to log lyrics String before put its in a TextView and print question marks too.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this before you put the lyrics into a textview:

```
newLyrics = new String(oldString.getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8");
```

Comment: Hi @MJ93, your solution is probably correct but not for me. My problem is on the encoding midi file that I get from web resource. I need to encode correctly the file before extract lyrics text with MIDI Api.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out once:

https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r92092/ref/midi/

Midi files basically comprises of binary format + ascii values as header data, so if you can convert that and represent it like-
If you can encode that binary format to base64, this will turn any data into ascii safe text

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
//String encode function
fun encodeEmoji(message: String): String {
    try {
        return URLEncoder.encode(
            message,
            "UTF-8"
        )
    } catch (e: UnsupportedEncodingException) {
        return message
    }

}


//String decode function
fun decodeEmoji(message: String): String {
    val myString: String? = null
    try {
        return URLDecoder.decode(
            message, "UTF-8"
        )
    } catch (e: UnsupportedEncodingException) {
            return message
    }

}
```

**use of function**

```
    var string:String=CommonMethod.encodeEmoji("your string")

    string=CommonMethod.decodeEmoji(string)
```